# issue with mysql workbench upgrading to fedora 23

Tags: fedora, dependencies, mysql-workbench

I have just upgraded to fedora 23 but mysql workbench is not installed anymore.
I tried to install the rpm like this (fc23 doesn't exist):

```
sudo rpm -i mysql-workbench-community-6.3.5-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm
```

but i got this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libzip.so.2()(64bit) is needed by mysql-workbench-community-6.3.5-1.fc22.x86_64
```

libzip is already installed, so I don't understand what it is happening...

```
$ sudo dnf install libzip
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:32:31 ago on Mon Nov 16 17:00:50 2015.
Package libzip-1.0.1-2.fc23.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
```

Comment: what about trying `sudo dnf install mysql-workbench-community-6.3.5-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm`? Preferably with some verbose mode.

Comment: It could be under a different name in Fedora 23.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just attempting the same upgrade and with mysql workbench also installed. My upgrade failed on this:
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libzip.so.4.0.0 from install of libzip-1.1-1.fc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libzip-last-1.1.3-1.fc22.remi.x86_64

When I initiated a dnf remove libzip-last, mysql-workbench-community was among those things would be removed, so I know that libzip-last is a dependency. I then installed the other items manually and they completed without requesting libzip-last, so it's a dependency ONLY of workbench.

I retried my upgrade, now without libzip-last ... the download skipped everything already downloaded and it completed successfully and is awaiting reboot. I'll wait for the upgrade to complete before reinstalling Workbench.

Comment: If you had at least waited to confirm that your suggestion works, it might have been more valuable but as it is, it is very low quality.